# How to generate a 9 digit number

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to use php to generate a 9 digit number that does not start with a 0 and is separated by dash every third number.

e.g. 102-394-458

I'm also debating whether

- to store it as a number or do the formatting on the front end
- or to store it as a number and do the formatting on the backend
- or to just store the dashes in the database as well

Of course the choice will affect how the number is generated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
implode('-',str_split(rand(100000000,999999999),3))
```

Generally, it's probably better simply to store as a number, and format it with the - only for display purposes

Comment: Toss in mt_rand and it's a win.

Comment: @banzaimonkey - Yup, should've used mt_rand(), but even rand() will should serve this purpose

Answer (score 6):

Use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/number_format) on the frontend. Storing it formatted will mean you will have to "deformat" it if you want to perform any operation with it that requires it being a number.

The way to generate such a number is:

```
$number = mt_rand(100000000,999999999);
```

You can use number_format like this:

```
echo number_format($number,0,"","-");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should save as an unsigned integer in your database and format on display (but still on server-side, if this is what you mean by backend.)

To generate the number use

```
mt_rand(100000000, 999999999);
```

To display use:

```
wordwrap($number, 3, '-', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number between 1 and 9.
Generate 8 random numbers between 0 and 9.
Combine them into a string, adding dashes where desired.